# ember-qunit moduleFor needs ember default controller

Tags: ember.js, qunit, ember-qunit

According to ember guides testing a controller that has needs is like this:

```
moduleFor('controller:comments', 'Comments Controller', {
  needs: ['controller:post']
});
```

In my case I have a custom `CommentsController` but i don't have a custom `PostController` and Ember creates one for me.

But ember-qunit complains that it cannot find `controller:post`. If i explicitly define it, it works fine.

Do i have to explicitly define every controller that ember-qunit tests?

Comment: If it's just a auto-generated controller, is it really necessary for your test?  Maybe you could expand on what you're testing and how it's necessary.  I can see how this is a limitation of ember-qunit though, and how this would work in a normal app just fine.

Comment: I just learned testing and saw that limitation asking just to make sure i am on the right track.